# NOOB: Tying DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder onto HttpClientCodec

Tags: netty

I have an HTTP response that comprises a bunch of 0-terminated entities.

I wish to handle each 0-terminated entity individually, and the obvious way to do so appears to hook in a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.

However, after HttpClientCodec, the message is an HttpResponse, or HttpChunk, whereas DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder (well, any FrameDecoder) wants to operate on a raw ChannelBuffer.

So, while I am confident I could hack something together, I would like to know the 'right' way to do this. Where 'right' might be variously defined as elegant, correct, and in the 'spirit' of Netty.

Apologies if this is too naive.

Roland

Answer (score 0):

FrameDecoders are very useful when your application directly uses TCP/UDP with own wire/frame format. Using them for this type of decoding will need an OneToOneDecoder handler, which converts DefaultHttpResponse to ChannelBuffer. If your application is receiving chucked responses, then you have to add a HttpChunkAggregator to the pipeline.

I prefer to have an simple upstream handler to decode DefaultHttpResponse to channelBuffer arrays, any way if you want to separate the decoding from you application handler, you can  have following pipeline.

```
  pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());
  pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));//optional
  ...
  pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
  pipeline.addLast("oneToOneDecoder", new Http2ChannelBufferDecoder extends OneToOneDecoder   {...})
  ...
  pipeline.addLast("delimiterDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you have presented a decoding pipeline for an HTTP server, no? My app is an HTTP client, which receives chunked responses. And I do want to handle chunks as they arrive. I presume HttpChunkAggregator stalls until a full message is complete?

Can you elaborate a little on 'I prefer to have an simple upstream handler to decode...'?

Comment: Yes, you are correct :), i have updated it.  HttpChunkAggregator waits until last chunk is received, then fire a message event with full HttpResponse. What I mean by using a simple upstream handler is, you can have a simple upstream handler implementation which replace last two handlers in the pipeline.